# How to make response of the object in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections

I have created an api to fetch all the instances details of Ec2, but I don't know how to make a proper response of it and send, currently I am using Array List but it is returning arrays of array.
How to make perfect response please help

My code -

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getAllInstances() {
        boolean done = false;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> instances = new ArrayList<>();
        DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
        while (!done) {
            DescribeInstancesResult response = ec2Client.describeInstances(request);
        
            for (Reservation reservation : response.getReservations()) {
                for (Instance instance : reservation.getInstances()) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add(instance.getInstanceId());
                    list.add(instance.getInstanceType());
                    list.add(instance.getState().getName());
                    System.out.printf(
                            "Found instance with id %s, " +
                                    "AMI %s, " +
                                    "type %s, " +
                                    "state %s " +
                                    "and monitoring state %s",
                            instance.getInstanceId(),
                            instance.getImageId(),
                            instance.getInstanceType(),
                            instance.getState().getName(),
                            instance.getMonitoring().getState());
                    instances.add(list);
         }
            }
            request.setNextToken(response.getNextToken());
            if (response.getNextToken() == null) {
                done = true;
            }
            System.out.println("flag stats = "+done);
        }
        return  instances;
    }
```

Response -

```
[["i-09xxxxxxf5b82","t2.nano","running"],["i-03ddxxxxx956d099","t2.micro","running"]]
```

How to make it proper json response.

Comment: Why not use json object mapping using a separate class for response, in that way u will have proper list of each instance with proper key value mapping?
moreover, what kind of response do u need? some clarity needed here

Comment: I want that response should be like - 
[{"id":"132sdsxxxx",
"type":"t2.nano",
"status',"running"},
{...}]

Comment: instead of ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>, you should try List<MyInstance>; here MyInstance can inherit properties of Instance only the ones you need; but u can use the Instance directly as well, it will just have extra params

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new class with the fields you need to return, i.e.:

```
public class InstanceDetails {
    private String instanceId;
    private String instanceType; // Could use an enum for this if you know all possible values
    private String state;
    // further fields as required
    // constructor / getters / setters
}
```

You could then create objects of this class instead of your list and add them to the instances list. Your function definition would thus be:

```
public List<InstanceDetails> getAllInstances() {

}
```

(As a side note, you might have done it for a reason but I usually use the abstract list type in method definitions, you can still return an ArrayList inside the method).

You might also need a JSON library (such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)) to parse the output depending on where you are sending it.